# Call method in child fragment in parent fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

In my `MainActivity class` I have view pager with 3 tab `fragmentHome class`, `fragmentHot class` and `FragmentCategoryclass`

Here is `fragmentCategory class`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view;
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentcategory, container, false);
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.category_fragment, new TabCategoryFragment());
  transaction.commit();
  return view;
}
```

In `TabCategoryFragment class`, I have grid category news and when click item grid I called:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("category", arrDataZone.get(position).getZone_name());
bundle.putString("zoneid", arrDataZone.get(position).getZone_id());
ListCategoryFragment myFrag = new ListCategoryFragment();
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.replace(R.id.category_fragment, myFrag,"listFramgnet");
transaction.addToBackStack("grid_category");
transaction.commit();
```

Now I want call method in `ListCategoryFragment` from `MainActivity` or call method in `ListCategoryFragment` from `FragmentCategory`.

Because I try call method in `FragmentCategory` from `MainACtivity` with:

```
linearPlayer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int number=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Fragment fragment= adapter.getItem(number);

    if (number==0) {
      ((FragmentHome)fragment).playAudioSerVice();
    } else if(number==1) {
      ((FragmentHot)fragment).playAudioSerVice();
    } else if( number==2) {
      ((FragmentNew)fragment).playAudioSerVice();
    } else if( number==3) {
      ((FragmentCategory)fragment).playAudioSerVice();
    }
  }
});
```

and it ran. Please give me your idea or code to do it.

[image]

Comment: Which method want to call from Activity?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no, I want call method  playAudioService() in ListCategoryFramgnet.class from MainActivty.class or from FragmentCategory.class

Comment: Then call it as `((MainActivty)getActivity())..playAudioSerVice();` is there any issue when doing this?

Comment: It ran very good, so I want from method playAudioSerVice() in FragmentCateogory.class I can call method playAudioService() in ListCategoryFragment.class if ListCategoryFragment.class showed

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I added image for my question. My english is poor

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK should use broadcast intent from MainActivity if number ==3?

Comment: Just want to know why you have same method code with same name in different classes ?  my suggestion is just create a method in MainActivity then call it from different Fragments by passing  file name which want to play from Fragments. is there any issue?

Comment: problem in here is when getCurrentItem==3 I only call method in FragmentCategory.class . FragmentCategory.class alway replace with TabFragmentCategory.class but How I can check if TabFragmentCateogty.class replace by ListCategoryFragment.class and call method in it from method in FragmentCategory? name of method is no fixed, can change any other name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eventbus postSticky to resolve it,you can see the api, [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/EventBus.java)

I wrote a demo to simulate your case.Here is the code.
MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contaner,new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void changeFragment(ChangeFragmentEvent event) {
        // get event from MainActivityFragment immediately--->EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChangeFragmentEvent());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contaner,PlusOneFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

MainActivityFragment:

```
    public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main22, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        View button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChangeFragmentEvent());//notify MainActivity change fragment
                EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MEvent());//send a msg to PlusOneFragment,when it shown 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PlusOneFragment:

```
    public class PlusOneFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlusOneFragment() {
    }

    public static PlusOneFragment newInstance() {
        PlusOneFragment fragment = new PlusOneFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plus_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true)
    public void getMEvent(MEvent event){
        // get event from MainActivityFragment when PlusOneFragment show --->EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MEvent());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello,there",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

}
```